# Why is this code working here but not on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, function

I have this simple code which has nothing wrong with it and it runs **here** but not on JSFiddle. On inspecting the console I find the following error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: fn is not defined`
**[LINK TO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v3gsmnvq/)**

```js
var fn = {
  one: function() {
    alert('1')
  },
  two: function() {
    alert('2')
  },
  three: function() {
    alert('3')
  }
};
```

```html
<button onclick='fn.one()'>1</button>
<button onclick='fn.two()'>2</button>
<button onclick='fn.three()'>3</button>
```

Comment: try to include jquery cdn in top of html section

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because jsfiddle sandboxes your code in a closure.

You can see that you wrote `var fn` (which makes a local var), just remove the `var` statement to make it global and you will be able to call it the way you are now.

Though, I'd advise you to use `addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a JSFiddle feature.  JSFiddle, by default, wraps all your code in a `$(document).ready()` handler.  To get your JS out of the wrapper and back into the flow of the normal DOM, just select the JSFiddle option under 'Frameworks & Extensions' and change it from 'onLoad' to 'No wrap - in head' or 'No wrap - in body'

Answer (score 1):

Change the drop down in jsfiddle from onLoad to No wrap - in head OR No wrap - in body.

Answer (score 1):

Change the option on the left from `onLoad` to one of the `no wrap` (i.e. `no wrap - in <head>` or `no wrap - in <body>` options and it runs with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

This code on jsfiddle doesnt work because this is how scope of variables works in JavaScript.

You can see that if I change only a few characters from

```
var fn = // the rest of code ...
```

to

```
window.fn = // the rest of code ...
```

Your example works "correctly" - http://jsfiddle.net/v3gsmnvq/7/

Read about scopes even here on SO: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)